# Tutorials for Android wear apps

Tags: android, wear-os

Iam starting to learn to develop Android wear apps. But I need some tutorials to follow so that I get a better idea.

Are there any tutorials which you could suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Check it: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-android-wear-hands-on--cms-22157

Comment: @Giridharan thank you .Just what I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Before you can develop anything for the wearable platform, you need to prepare your development environment by installing and updating all the packages you'll need, ensuring your Android Studio IDE is up to date.
- open the Android SDK Manager and check you have the latest versions of the following three packages:

  1. SDK Tools
  2. Platform tools
  3. Build tools.

For More Reference and Tutorial check this link:  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-android-wear-hands-on--cms-22157