# wearable app start on handheld app launch

Tags: android, wear-os

I am new in android, now I want to know is there any way that my application will start automatically when I start application on handheld, or can I trigger the application on a particular time ?

Comment: Do you want to open your application in both mobile and wearable at the same time right?

Comment: yes exactly that's what i want,

Comment: Check this- https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/all-about-wearables---an-android-wear-tutorial

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-android-wear-hands-on--cms-22157

Comment: Read this also-http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359650/tutorials-for-android-wear-apps/28360677#28360677

Comment: thanks a lot...........